# does this LEFT OUTER JOIN statement look correct?

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js, tedious

I' not getting an error message but i seem to be only getting 5 results no matter what i choose, so this leaves me to beleive that there is something wrong with my SQL statement. I'm usint node.js tedious to connect to sql 2008 r2 database. Previous statements worked, but that was a simple select statement with the posting date where clause. I know there are spaces in my column names which is not good practice, but there is nothing i can do about that this because thedatabase is utilized by Navision. Normally there are no line breaks, i just did that to make it appear more orderly to you guys.

```
SELECT 
    TA.[Amount],  
    TA.[Posting Date],  
    TA.[Entry No_],  
    TA.[Document No_],  
    TB.[Salesperson Code] 
FROM [ShowTex Belgie NV$G_L Entry] as TA  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [ShowTex Belgie NV$Sales Invoice Header] as TB  
    ON TA.[Document No_]=TB.[No_] 
WHERE TA.[Posting Date]>'05/01/2015'  
    AND TA.[Document Type]='2'  
    AND TA.[Gen_ Posting Type]='2'
```

**Strangely Enough the SQL turns out not to be the issu.** It is the conversion from JSON.stringify to JSON.parse. I was certain i had tested this successfully before. But perhaps i was negligent. Anyways My code looks like this. when i Console.log(retVal) the data still looks correct about 100 reccords as expected.

```
retVal = JSON.stringify({result:dataSet});
fn(retVal);


function fn(retVal){
    var obj = JSON.parse(retVal);   
    for(var i = 0; i<Object.keys(obj.result[0]).length;i++){
        console.log(obj.result[i]);
    }
}
```

If i console.log(retVal) inside the fn function i still get my wall of text as expected. but within the FOR statement i only get the first 5 records. Hmm I bet I'm headbutting a rookie mistake at the moment. :/

Comment: We don't know your data.  How many rows are you expecting back?  Show some table structure and sample data or create a SQLFiddle if you want to get a good answer.

Comment: Are you perhaps using `AND` where you should be using `OR`?  Syntactically everything looks correct.

Comment: How many rows do you get back if you leave the `where` clause but remove the left join (and the last column in your `select`)?  If it is also 5, then the join is not the problem.

Comment: Thanks for feedback guys, i just got home; cant log in to server from here so ill have to check tomorrow morning.

Comment: My guess: The database library you're using has the max rows set to a default of 5. Run the query on the command line or similar "direct" interface.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wow, i found my problem. It's really embarrassing, the SQL was correct, i was counting the number of columns in my json file, this returned 5 each time. Sorry for Wasting people's time. Thank you so much for your feedback. It was helpfull in a sense that i was fixated on getting my sql statement wrong because I'm not good at those so your feedback was helpfull. It never occurred to me that I could still be running into rookie mistakes likes this.

```
i<Object.keys(obj.result[0]).length
```

needs to be

```
i<Object.keys(obj.result).length
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally depends on what you want but here is a cheat sheet with venn diagrams. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg so that it might be more logically to see what you are doing.